# Postgres, FATAL ошибка при реплики базы

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql, ssh, psql

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь настроить реплику БД.
Postgres отказывается запускаться, ссылаясь на ошибку:

```
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3687-1] FATAL:  database system identifier differs between the primary and standby
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3687-2] DETAIL:  The primary's identifier is 6300853119170962464, the standby's identifier is 6343126169967713718.
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3690-1] postgres@postgres PANIC:  could not open critical system index 2671
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3621-22] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3621-23] LOG:  server process (PID 3690) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2016-10-27 18:04:32 MSK [3621-24] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2016-10-27 18:04:33 MSK [3621-25] LOG:  abnormal database system shutdown
```

Сам psql тоже не запускается, выдавая:

```
root@ProLiant-DL160-G6:/var/log/postgresql# psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Как можно починить?

Comment: Что делали с базой на master? Откатывали?

Answer (score 2):

Коллега, следуйте документации. 
Вы, вероятно, просто скопировали файлы базы на новый сервер. Это в корне неверно.

Как правильно включить репликацию postgresql:
    Создайте пользователя

```
CREATE USER replica
SUPERUSER 
LOGIN 
CONNECTION LIMIT 1 
ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'MyStrongPassword'; 

Откройте этому пользователю доступ для реплицкации (pg_hba.conf):

host replication replica 127.0.0.1/0 md5
```

На всякий включите логи соединений:

```
log_connections = on
```

Включите хотя бы один отправитель wal-логов на мастере:

```
max_wal_senders = 1 
wal_mode = 'archive' 
archive_mode = on 
archive_command = 'cd .'
```

Попутно укажите количество сегментов лога для хранения. 1 сегмент = 16 МБ изменений.

```
wal_keep_segments = 10000 # e.g. 160 GB 

Сделайте бэкап (Средствами pg и rsync!)
```

1. Поехали:

   ```
   psql -c "select pg_start_backup('Start backup for slave-server')"
   ```
2. Копируем все данные, кроме WAL-логов:

   ```
   rsync -cva --inplace --exclude=*pg_xlog* \ 
   ${PGDATA}/ $secondnode:$PGDATA
   ```
3. Выключаем режим бэкапа, когда всё скопировалось:

   psql -c "select pg_stop_backup(), current_timestamp"
4. Правим файл recovery.conf:

   Standby_mode = 'on' 
   primary_conninfo = 'host=192.168.0.1 user=replica' 
   trigger_file = '/tmp/postgresql.trigger.5432'

Ну и запускаем slave сервак (standby, в терминологии postgre)

Comment: Делал всё согластно этой инструкции: https://www.8host.com/blog/replikaciya-baz-dannyx-postgresql-po-tipu-masterslave/ Видимо где-то допустил ошибку. попробую начать с начала. P.S. Слейв к мастеру подключается ок.

Comment: Судя по ошибке - вот это забыли или не сработало: psql -c "select pg_start_backup('initial_backup');"

Comment: к сожалению - нет. все команды ввёл. всё как в маньюале, но в конце всё равно: FATAL: incorrect checksum in control file